# PHP OOP Learning Curve - MySQL Object Failure

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm currently learning PHP and I'm new to OOP. I'm trying to create an object to handle MySQL queries and connections.

This is what I've created so far:

```
class MySQLDatabase {

    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this->open_connection();
    }

    public function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die(
                "Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . 
                " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
            );
        } 
    }

    public function close_connection() {
        if(isset($this->connection)) {
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $cleaned_sql = mysqli::real_escape_string($sql);
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $cleaned_sql);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }

    public function mysql_prep($string) {           
        $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $string);
        return $escaped_string;
    }

    private function confirm_query($result) {
        if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

And on the public-facing side (doing a test to make sure things work as expected):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, first_name, last_name) ";
$sql .= "VALUES (1, 'jbloggs', 'secretpwd', 'Joe', 'Bloggs')";
$result = $database->query($sql);
```

Currently, I just get the output of:
Database query failed.

The issue seems to be something to do with my mysql_prep function, as when I remove that all works fine.

Any advice is greatly welcomed.

Thanks in advance!
Alex.

Comment: *"Currently, I just get the output of: Database query failed."* - You need to find out what the real error was.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Error appears to be related to my  mysql_prep function, as when this is removed things appear to work fine.

Comment: You are supposed to clean variables NOT a complete query

Comment: If you are learning OOP then wrapping an existing database access object is that last thing you shoud be doing. Wait till you have a good idea about OO before attempting something that most good programmers get wrong

Comment: Also Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not putting anything in to production, have a long way to go before fully at grasps with it, clearly. Just doing a bit of learning with it and testing myself to see what I am able to do, but yes completely understand that it shouldn't be taken lightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running your ENTIRE query through the escape function, which is exactly the **WRONG** thing to do. That eliminates any quotes necessary for the query to be syntactically correct.

Consider this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('baz')
```

Since you're escaping the entire thing, you're sending this to the database:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (\'bar\')
```

since those quotes are escape, they're not quotes anymore. they're plaintext characters, and the DB is looking for a field named `'bar'` to get a value from. You can't look up a field in a record for insertion, because you're INSERTING the record and it doesn't exist yet. And `'bar'` is unlikely to exist in your table definition.

So your query fails with a syntax error, and since you have a fixed/unchanging/useless "failed" message, you never get told the reason WHY it failed.

At least change your die() to something like

```
die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($this->connection));
```

Comment: Whoops, derp moment. Thanks very much, makes a lot more sense and duly noted :-)